# TemplateSYntax error : no module named 

Tags: django, module

I pretty much know what i have to do  , yet it doesn't work . Maybe your fresh eye will see the problem .

**So** .. My project name is : **pro**  . Its location is  **/home/username/pro/**

I have several application in pro folder, like : **blog** , **comments** etc. Everything works fine. But if i change the structure for apps  from pro/blog , pro/comments to pro/apps/blog/, pro/apps/comments/  i get TemplateSyntax error: no module named ..... everytime i try to import application in settings.py.

Here is my apache main configuration , there is some more , but not relative to this topic :

```
<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE pro.settings
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/home/username/'] + sys.path"
</Location>
```

As i understand my problem , the reason why it gives me this error because path to applications is not in python path. Yet when i try to change python path to :    PythonPath "['/home/username/','/home/username/pro/','/home/username/pro/apps/'] + sys.path" . Nothing changes.

Comment: Did you update the names in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? (remember they're full app package paths)

Comment: @bradley  I am not sure what you mean by update ? If u mean did i add it to INSTALLED_APPS  ,then ofcourse . Restarted apache ... If something else , then probably not.

Comment: I mean, did you add the `.apps` piece of the path to each of your apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @bradley . Sure . INSTALLED_APPS = ((...,'pro.apps.blog',))

Comment: And so what's the actual module name that it's looking for but can't find?

Comment: @bradley  TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named apps.blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` to the folder containing your apps.

PS: Adding `pro/apps` to your pythonpath would make your apps resolvable via `INSTALLED_APPS=('blog',)`.

Comment: Yeah . Thx . You are right. It is resolvable via INSTALLED_APPS=('blog',). Now everything works fine . I knew i jsut missed something =) .

Comment: But, more likely, you forgot `__init__.py` and you don't need to modify your python path. It's better to use `myproject.myapp`

Comment: Nope .. __init__.py was there . I just messed up with installed_apps . The way i implemented it. Your answer was correct .

Comment: Really? That's super mysterious. Your syntax above should have worked without resorting to adding the apps to the global path. Well, I'm glad you have a solution!

Comment: I just now tried... The funny thing is that i removed everything from python path , except path to the main project. And everything works like this INSTALLED_APPS=('blog',).  I just dont udnerstand why in  Installed_APPS  blog should be declared just like 'blog' ,but  another application which is not in the /pro/apps/ , but is in /pro/     must be declared like pro.blog .

Comment: @Yuji By my logic if app is on /pro/  , then it should be declared as pro.app , if it is in /pro/apps/  then it should be declared as  pro.apps.blog .... But instead it is pro.blog  , and if in /pro/apps/   then just 'blog'

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you forgot to put a `__init__.py` in your `apps` directory to make it a package. It must be a package for you to be able to import things from it in Python.